# Win32: Modal dialog not returning focus

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I'm writing a win32 wrapper classes, mainly to learn more about win32 programming.
To get around the problem of c-style callbacks, the following method stores/retrieves the pointer using SetWindowLong/GetWindowLong and passes it to the actual winproc.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WinClass::WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // On window creation, WindowProc receives lParam as a LPCREATESTRUCT 
    // Store *this* pointer as long in GWL_USERDATA
    if (msg == WM_NCCREATE)
        ::SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<long>(reinterpret_cast<LPCREATESTRUCT>(lParam)->lpCreateParams));

    // Retrieve the pointer
    WinClass *wnd = reinterpret_cast<WinClass*>(::GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA));

    // Call the actual winproc function
    if (wnd)
        return wnd->WndProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    // Default to DefWindowProc message handler function
    return ::DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Winclass is the class wrapping the main window created by CreateWindowEx. The same WindowProc function is part of the MDlgClass wrapping the modal dialog. I'm calling the dialog like this

```
DialogBox(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(id), hwnd, DialogProc);
```

If I pass NULL as the hWndParent, the dialog works okay as a modeless dialog but if I pass hwnd, the handle to the main window as hWndParent the dialog works correctly as a modal dialog. However when i close the dialog it doesnt pass control back to the main parent window? Debugging in Visual Studio shows its hanging in the message pump in WinMain.

I thought of using a hashmap to map the pointers but I'd rather do it using GetWindowLong etc. Is this possible? I've tried storing the dialog pointer in DWL_USER but it doesnt help.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm still getting my head around Win32.

EDIT: I'm destroying the dialog using EndDialog

EDIT: I'm storing the pointer in the GWL_USERDATA region of the main window, which is not used by windows and I'm only modifying it in WinClass::WindowProc when the window is first created. If I don't instantiate a dialog class, I know the pointer is being accessed correctly since the application responds to menu commands processed via WindowProc and WM_COMMAND.

Answer (score 6):

You can't use a WindowProc as a DialogProc. Window Procedures call DefWindowProc when they don't handle a message and return a meaningful result when they do.
Dialog Procedures return FALSE when they don't process a message, return TRUE when they DO, (except when they handle `WM_INITDIALOG`) and, if they have a meaningful result that they need to return from the outer window procedure, that is placed in `DWL_MSGRESULT`.

When you call the modal dialog box function, DialogBox, it enters a message pumping loop - which does dispatch messages to all windows in the thread so all windows continue to paint and process input - when the dialog is closed (using EndDialog), the DialogBox procedure should return.

When making a class to wrap dialog boxes, the usual method is to pass the 'this' pointer to One of the DialogBoxParam functions - which can be directly extracted from the `WM_INITDIALOG` message.

Answer (score 0):

How are you closing the window? Are you using `DestroyWindow`? While the child window is live, the parent window will be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You're saving a pointer to lpCreateParams.  Is it possible that the associated memory block is being freed or otherwise destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

```
//static method
BOOL CALLBACK WinClass::DlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  // Store *this* pointer as long in GWL_USERDATA
  if (msg == WM_INITDIALOG)
  {
        ::SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, DWLP_USER, reinterpret_cast(lParam));
        m_hWnd = hWnd; // I assume you really don't want to keep passing the hwnd around
  }

   WinClass* wnd = reinterpret_cast(::GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA));
   if (wnd)
       return wnd->DlgProcImpl(umsg, wParam, lParam);
   return FALSE;
}

BOOL WinClass::DlgProcImpl(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        // your code goes here

            return FALSE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}

INT_PTR WinClass:DoModalDialog(HINSTANCE hInst, HWND hwndParent, LPCTSTR template)
{
    return ::DialogBoxParam(hInst, template, hwndParent, WinClass::DlgProc, this);
}
```